# Why airflow KubernetesPodOperator resouce can not parse job trigger parameters

Tags: airflow

1. problem: I used airflow KubernetesPodOperator with a resource which gets from job trigger parameters, but got the following error log

```
[2020-12-24 12:19:36,166] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '683111d0-7af3-45c5-9bdc-26353fc7e140', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:19:36 GMT', 'Content-Length': '584'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Pod in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Pod: v1.Pod.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Resources: v1.ResourceRequirements.Limits: unmarshalerDecoder: quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$', error found in #10 byte of ...|.conf.cpu\", \"memory\"|..., bigger context ...|\"resources\": {\"limits\": {\"cpu\": \"dag_run.conf.cpu\", \"memory\": \"dag_run.conf.memory\"}, \"requests\": {\"|...","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

It seems that parameters`dag_run.conf.cpu` and `dag_run.conf.memory` were not parsed! And I have tried that set resource as a static value, and it works! But I don't why parameters were not parsed.

2. code: the code as follow

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow import configuration as conf

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}


dag = DAG('example_kubernetes_pod',
          schedule_interval='@once',
          default_args=default_args)  


# it not work and got the error 
with dag:
    k = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace='test',
        image="hello-world",
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        name="airflow-test-pod",
        task_id="task-one",
        in_cluster=in_cluster, 
        cluster_context='docker-for-desktop',
        config_file=config_file,
        resources={"request_cpu": "{{ dag_run.conf.cpu }}",
                   "request_memory": "{{ dag_run.conf.memory }}",
                   "limit_cpu": "{{ dag_run.conf.cpu }}",
                   "limit_memory": "{{ dag_run.conf.memory }}"},
       
       )

# it works
with dag:
    k = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace='test',
        image="hello-world",
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        name="airflow-test-pod",
        task_id="task-one",
        in_cluster=in_cluster, 
        cluster_context='docker-for-desktop',
        config_file=config_file,
        resources={"request_cpu": "4",
                   "request_memory": "8G",
                   "limit_cpu": "4",
                   "limit_memory": "8G"},
       
       )
```

3. I triggered this job with parameter:

```
{
    "cpu":"4",
    "memory":"8G"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this syntax: **{{ dag_run.conf['conf1'] }}**?

Something like this:

```
with dag:
    k = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace='test',
        image="hello-world",
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        name="airflow-test-pod",
        task_id="task-one",
        in_cluster=in_cluster, 
        cluster_context='docker-for-desktop',
        config_file=config_file,
        resources={"request_cpu": "{{ dag_run.conf['cpu'] }}",
                   "request_memory": "{{ dag_run.conf['memory'] }}",
                   "limit_cpu": "{{ dag_run.conf['cpu'] }}",
                   "limit_memory": "{{ dag_run.conf['memory'] }}"},
       
       )
```

I read about it here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#passing-parameters-when-triggering-dags

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but got the same  error message

Answer (score 0):

Airflow (current 2.1) doesn't supports template for resources